# Can't access VPN after connecting to L2TP IPsec VPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, ubuntu-mate, l2tp

I can't seem to access this VPN despite successfully connecting to it. I am using UbuntuMate 18.04 and it is a L2TP VPN. I know my credentials are correct because I am able to access stuff on my android phone with my credentials, but not on my Ubuntu desktop.

Basically the exact same problem as [this guy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29047/cant-access-internet-after-connecting-to-l2tp-ipsec-vpn), but the answers there are not helping. Any advice on what I could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I figured out that this was a problem with my routing table. This can be solved when you set up the vpn by clicking the IPv4 tab in the connection's editor and then clicking routs. Add the IP of the vpn network you are trying to connect too (this is not the same as the gateway you put in the VPN tab), add 255.255.255.255 in the netmask so we only get the one ip address, and 0.0.0.0 for the Gateway, and check "Use this connection only for resources on its network".

[Here is where I found my info.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84516/how-to-set-routes-for-my-vpn-connection)